# Chrome keeps redirecting to old domain name after change only one letter to the new domain name

Tags: google-chrome

I was working on one website and mid process the client realized they made mistake in domain name and missed one letter from the name.

Now they changed the domain name and i did everything properly on changing all url, DNS, hosting data, etc... to the new domain name, the difference is only one letter.

For example:

Old domain `domainname.tld`
New domain `domainnames.tld`

And now Chrome is making me problems and not letting me go to new domain name. A few times there was notification like did you mean going to the old domain name, sometimes attackers mimic domain names...

[image]

The screenshot is made before Chrome completely stopped asking me and just started redirecting me.

I know everything is set for sure good because intodns is reporting everything ok, on all other browsers i have installed on my PC (Edge, Firefox, Opera) i can open the website and surf with new domain name

Comment: There exists  alias for several domains to show the same page. I believe that your new domain name is acting as an alias of old domain name. You need to reconfigure the DNS.

Comment: It's not dns, the domain is not added as alias, everything works fine on other browsers and devices, it's just my chrome.